# How to calculate C-SCAN algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, io, operating-system, scheduling, disk

I'm learning operating system disk management algorithm. There is a specific algorithm called C-SCAN which is a variant of [SCAN (or elevator) disk scheduling algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elevator_algorithm). Now in the [example section of Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elevator_algorithm#Example), there is an example of calculating SCAN vs C-SCAN method.

In case of C-SCAN when the head is moved from 100 to 0 we are calculating the whole seek time of 100. But I think if C-SCAN is imagined as scanning a cylinder then why would we consider the jump as a seek time?

[image]

There is an [another article](http://www.cs.iit.edu/~cs561/cs450/disksched/disksched.html) where the jump is not calculated. So what to do? I would be glad if anyone answer my question with proper example.

Answer (score 2):

The algorithms aren't talking about the '100' as a time, but rather the distance the head will move. The numbers they refer too are track numbers (cylinders are logically all the tracks above and below each other when viewed from above the disk). So track 20 and 21 are neighbours for the examples given.

The elevator technique is pretty simple, once you start going in a direction, keep going until you have no more requests in that direction, then change direction and go all the way in the other direction.  Think of it like a book, you are on page (track) 20, so keep going forward, until the end, then work through the book backwards.

C-SCAN is similiar, except rather than reversing direction at the end, it goes back to the extreme lowest and starts again.

The are subtle differences in I/O latency under high load with these two variations even though they appear very close.

Comment: from [this article](http://www.cs.iit.edu/~cs561/cs450/disksched/disksched.html) *"Keep in mind that the huge jump doesn't count as a head movement"* and in Wiki example the jump is calculated as movement. So which to consider?

Comment: Try this, http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~remzi/OSTEP/file-disks.pdf reasonably good and bit more extended.

Comment: But [this](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~remzi/OSTEP/file-disks.pdf) still doesn't answer my question. Should I **consider the jump count or not**?

Comment: Logically, the head moves from end back to zero (ie the return to zero part), but in reality it physically moves to next/lowest pending track, in typical implementations, so no the dotted return count need not be counted.

Comment: Yes, but see the comment at end.  Note: Even though six seeks were performed using the C-SCAN algorithm, only five I/Os were actually done.

Comment: Yes. Actually I was confuse about calculating the jump or not.